# Where the new pages get stored after creation in django CMS?

Tags: python, django-cms

I am creating the new page in Django CMS. I want to see where the HTML pages get stored?

I tried to find out every where also in the `site-package`, but I was not able to find it. Can anyone tell me when I create a new page in Django CMS in GUI view, then where it get stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in the database you configured for Django. By default you can inspect the pages in the administration interface at `/admin/cms/page/`. In the database the table for them is by default named `cms_page`.

Comment: It seems like they are indexed there but I don't see any page content